# Interpreting intercept with a categorical predictor

Tags: regression, categorical-data, predictor, intercept

I have a categorical predictor (segment) and continuous DV (income). 'segment' is a factor with 6 levels. I ran a simple regression in R and got the following results:

Deviance Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-79243  -39259  -22638    5235  730633

Coefficients:

```
                       Estimate Std. Error t value     Pr(>|t|)    
     (Intercept)         79367      13510   5.874 0.0000000151 ***
     segmentSegment2    -55827      20771  -2.688      0.00773 ** 
     segmentSegment3    -32444      18073  -1.795      0.07397 .  
     segmentSegment4    -36729      19328  -1.900      0.05866 .  
     segmentSegment5    -30563      22062  -1.385      0.16732    
     segmentSegment6    -18841      22062  -0.854      0.39401    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 8213968357)

      Null deviance: 1923983664930  on 231  degrees of freedom
      Residual deviance: 1856356848731  on 226  degrees of freedom
      AIC: 5962.7

      Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Does this mean that being in segment 1 is more predictive of higher income, whereas being in segment 2 is associated with having less income? This does not make sense to me because the estimate of segment 4 is less than segment 2, so should this not mean that being in segment 4 is more strongly associated with less income?

Comment: Is this Poisson regression?

Comment: No, I used the glm() function- it assumes Gaussian distribution

Answer (score 1):

This is your model:

$$\hat y = \beta_1+\beta_2 X_2+\beta_3 X_3+\beta_4 X_4+\beta_5 X_5+\beta_6 X_6$$

Since you are using R's defaults, that implies your categorical variable is encoded with a contrast matrix.
For each segment we get:

$$
X_\text{segment 1} = [0,0,0,0,0] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 1} = \beta_1\\
X_\text{segment 2} = [1,0,0,0,0] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 2} = \beta_1+\beta_2\\
X_\text{segment 3} = [0,1,0,0,0] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 3} = \beta_1+\beta_3\\
X_\text{segment 4} = [0,0,1,0,0] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 4} = \beta_1+\beta_4\\
X_\text{segment 5} = [0,0,0,1,0] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 5} = \beta_1+\beta_5\\
X_\text{segment 6} = [0,0,0,0,1] \rightarrow \hat y_\text{segment 6} = \beta_1+\beta_6\\
$$

This means that $\beta_1$ (the intercept) represents the mean effect observed in segment 1.
However, to get the mean effect for segment 2, you should look instead for $\beta_1 + \beta_2$. Intuitively, $\beta_2$ represents the additional effect observed from that one already observed in segment 1.

Running your numbers, these are the expected values:

```
     segmentSegment1    79367      
     segmentSegment2    23540     
     segmentSegment3    46923     
     segmentSegment4    42638     
     segmentSegment5    48804     
     segmentSegment6    60526
```

Onto the rest of your questions:

> Does this mean that being in segment 1 is more predictive of higher income, whereas being in segment 2 is associated with having less income?

Yes, and this difference is prima facie significant.

> This does not make sense to me because the estimate of segment 4 is less than segment 2, so should this not mean that being in segment 4 is more strongly associated with less income?

No, the effect of being in segment 4 compared to one is a prima facie non-significant reduction of just 36729, compared to that of 55827 for segment 2.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Would it be fair to say then that there is a significant association with income and segments 1 and 2? People categorised into segment 1 are more likely to have higher income, which those in segment 2 are most likely to have a lower income?

Could you also explain the difference between expected values and averages? I am a little confused because when I look at the average income per segment, while segment 1 has the highest average income, segment 5 follows.

Comment: @Rnovice due to the contrasts, we can say that income is significantly different from zero in segment 1, and that income is significantly different between segments 1 and 2. You can test other differences as well.